# STM32-RTC counts the time wrong

Tags: c, arm, embedded

With the following clock setup:
[image: [This is Clock Setup Image][1].]
RTC counts the clock incorrectly.
The LSE frequency I use is 32.768kHz.
The clock goes 30 seconds a day.
Normally, the RTC shows 12:30:30 when it is normally 12:30:00.
Is this from the hardware or is it from the software?
The software section looks like this:

```
void vRTCInit(void)
{
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24/*RTC_HOURFORMAT_12*/;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

My system clock setups are as follows:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI
                                     | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV16;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection =  RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC | RCC_PERIPHCLK_LPTIM1
                                        | RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.Lptim1ClockSelection = RCC_LPTIM1CLKSOURCE_LSE;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_SYSCLK;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSE;//LSE
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /**Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW );

  /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /**Configure the Systick interrupt time
  */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000);

  /**Configure the Systick
  */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /**Enable MSI Auto calibration
  */
  HAL_RCCEx_EnableMSIPLLMode();

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15, 0);
}
```

If you notice, I set the RTC clock to LSE.

Comment: Most likely caused by the hardware, as you need a high precision oscillator for this. The question cannot be answered since you don't show how you set up the system clock for the MCU. It could be using a crappy internal RC oscillator for all we know.

Comment: We need more info to be able to answer your question. Please post more info related to how your clock tree is set up.

Comment: My LSE crystal is "CFS-206.CFS-145.CFV-206".(±20ppm).Could the issue be caused by the capacitor values in hardware? My capacitor values are 6.8pF (ceramic).

Comment: You'll have to ask hardware questions over at https://electronics.stackexchange.com. I would advise to copy/paste this question as-in, but include a schematic and part number of the oscillator in the question (there's a simple scematics tool over at EE) and then delete this question here on SO, since cross-posting is discouraged.

Comment: The load capacitance can have significant effects on frequency:  http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/c6/eb/5e/11/e3/69/43/eb/CD00221665.pdf/files/CD00221665.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00221665.pdf - it is probably not a software question.

Comment: The RTC on most STM32 parts is calibratable you can set the calibration to compensate for your gross error (347ppm), though ideally you'd calibrate it against a better oscillator such as a TCXO HSE driving the SYSCLK or a GPS 1PPS input for example.  If the error you are seeing is due to "crystal-pull" a fixed calibration will likely get you at least back into the realms of 20ppm at room temperature.